# How can I add refresh or conflict property

Tags: elasticsearch, jest-client

I wanted to add the query parameter ?refresh=true or ?conflict=true query parameter using Jest client SDK of java but I see setURI method of Jest client has protected access.

How can I able to set the URI and query param as jest client setURI method has protected access?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with

```
IndexRequest.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE)
UpdateRequest.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE)
```

Comment: I do not find method setRefreshPolicy, I am using elastic search SDK version 7.14.0, 

which version should I choose? 

also I am executing a query using jestClient.execute, can you please provide detailed example for building a complete queury using this?